# Save as in current directory and concatenate with a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

xlsm in the current folder location and concatenate the value of a cell value before the name

thanx

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()

Dim nom As String
nom = Dir(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
Range("F700").Value = nom
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("G63").Value & "_" & nom
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay - what's your question? Does your code not work? Does it throw an error (if so, what error, where)? Does it run, but not save? Does it ....

Comment: It works partly but do not save in the current location the workbook is

Comment: Do you perhaps mean to do `...SaveAs Filename:=nom & Range("G63").Value`? What's in `G63`? What is `nom`?

Comment: nom is name in french

Comment: My problem is that my workbook do not save in his current directory

Comment: You're not specifying a folder, `nom` doesn't contain a path. So the file gets saved in the current directory - probably *My Documents*. Use `ThisWorkbook.Path` to specify the full path, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312398/1188513) sugests.

Comment: Yes it goes in My documents but where I put Thisworkbook.Path to make it work in my code

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this.

```
Sub SaveToRelativePath()
    Dim relativePath As String
    relativePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relativePath
End Sub
```